# Decrement (or increment) operator in return statement in Java

Tags: java

I was implementing pagination in my web application (using Spring and Hibernate) where I needed the stuff something like the following.

```
public static int deleteSingle(long totalRows, long pageSize, int currentPage)
{
   return totalRows==currentPage*pageSize-pageSize ? currentPage-- : currentPage;
}
```

Suppose, I invoke this method from somewhere as follows.

```
deleteSingle(24, 2, 13);
```

With these arguments, the condition is satisfied and the value of the variable `currentPage` (i.e 13) minus 1 (i.e 12) should be returned but it doesn't decrement the value of `currentPage`. It returns the original value which is 13 after this call.

---

I had to change the method like the following for it to work as expected.

```
public static int deleteSingle(long totalRows, long pageSize, int currentPage)
{
    if(totalRows==currentPage*pageSize-pageSize)
    {
        currentPage=currentPage-1;   //<-------
        return currentPage;          //<-------
    }
    else
    {
        return currentPage;
    }
}
```

So why doesn't it decrement the value by 1 with the decrement operator - `currentPage--`? Why does it need - `currentPage=currentPage-1;` in this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your return statement, it uses `currentPage--` which causes the decrement after the return. You'd want `--currentPage` to do the decrement before the return. Personally, with a complicated statement like that, you probably want to break it out anyway for readability's sake, but that's a matter of preference.

(Technically, it decrements after it's read. There's nothing special about it being a return statement that changes when it decremements.)

If it were up to my, my taste would be to do this:

```
public static int deleteSingle(long totalRows, long pageSize, int currentPage)
{
    if(totalRows==currentPage*pageSize-pageSize)
    {
        currentPage--;
    }
    return currentPage;

}
```

Comment: Still, as the `--` or `++` does nothing, the compilers could create a warning or compile error. Maybe findbugs would find it?

Comment: @owlstead but the operator does do something. I do believe there is a findbugs check for that, though, is what the operator does is not always what the programmer wanted it to do.

Comment: How could the decrement happens after the method returns?

Comment: Because `currentPage` is just a number in memory somewhere. It's pretty useless to decrement it, considering it's a parameter and can't be read after the return, but it does indeed happen. (Chances are the optimizer will actually remove the bytecode that performs it, but logically there's no reason to assume it won't get decremented, and just be accessed by nothing.)

Answer (score 4):

Note that `x--` decrements `x` *after* using its value, you probably want `--currentPage`, which would decrement the variable *before* using its value.

---

To see this, consider:

```
public static int deleteSingle(long totalRows, long pageSize, int currentPage) {
    try {
        return totalRows == currentPage * pageSize - pageSize ? currentPage--
                    : currentPage;
    } finally {
        System.out.println("*" + currentPage);  // value after return
    }
}
```

Calling `deleteSingle(24, 2, 13)` prints:

```
*12
13
```

If we replace `currentPage--` with `--currentPage`, we receive:

```
*12
12
```

as expected.

**But**, don't you think it would be better to simply use `currentPage - 1` instead? There is no reason to *reassign* `currentPage` in this scenario (remember, such a reassignment will not be visible outside the scope of the method).

---

The prefix decrement operator is covered in [§15.15.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.2) of the JLS. Notice the sentence:

> The value of the prefix decrement expression is the value of the variable *after* the new value is stored.

Comment: How could the decrement happens after the method returns?

Comment: It doesn't happen after the method returns, it's just that the result of the operation `x--` is not the *new* value of `x` but instead the original value (before the decrement). The variable is decremented regardless. In other words, both `x--` and `--x` perform the same action on `x`, but they *return* different values.